# T-SQL generate XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a table with following structure

```
StreetNumber varchar(50)
Apartment varchar(50)
Floor varchar(50)
```

I want to convert the data to XML like this:

```
<Attributes>
    <AddressAttribute ID="1">
        <AddressAttributeValue>
            <Value>3</Value>
        </AddressAttributeValue>
    </AddressAttribute>
    <AddressAttribute ID="3">
        <AddressAttributeValue>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </AddressAttributeValue>
    </AddressAttribute>
    <AddressAttribute ID="2">
        <AddressAttributeValue>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </AddressAttributeValue>
    </AddressAttribute>
</Attributes>
```

Is there any way to convert each column to element with the same name and differs only with attribute `ID`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the XML in a subquery in the column list where you unpivot the values in a table constructor, giving each column an ID.

Here is a sample that uses a table variable as the source of data. You should of course use your table instead.

```sql
declare @T table
(
  StreetNumber varchar(50),
  Apartment varchar(50),
  Floor varchar(50)
);

insert into @T values('Street', 'Apartment', 'Floor');

select (
       select R.ID as '@ID',
              R.Value as 'AddressAttributeValue/Value'
       from (values(1, T.StreetNumber),
                   (2, T.Apartment),
                   (3, T.Floor)) as R(ID, Value)
       for xml path('AddressAttribute'), root ('Attributes'),  type
       )
from @T as T;
```

Result:

```xml
<Attributes>
  <AddressAttribute ID="1">
    <AddressAttributeValue>
      <Value>Street</Value>
    </AddressAttributeValue>
  </AddressAttribute>
  <AddressAttribute ID="2">
    <AddressAttributeValue>
      <Value>Apartment</Value>
    </AddressAttributeValue>
  </AddressAttribute>
  <AddressAttribute ID="3">
    <AddressAttributeValue>
      <Value>Floor</Value>
    </AddressAttributeValue>
  </AddressAttribute>
</Attributes>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. Can I prevent selecting an empty element? For example, I don't need whole `AddressAttribute` element without value.

Comment: @SergеуIsupov add à where clause to the sub query. `where R.Value is not null`

Answer (score 1):

There is one accepted answer already, which is great. Just as an alternative...

Short explanation: Normally the engine would not allow to place several elements with the same name in the same level in one go. But the `,''` (empty elements) in between tell the engine to close one element and to start a new one.

```
DECLARE @Addr TABLE(StreetNumber varchar(50),Apartment varchar(50),Floor varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Addr VALUES('SomeStreet', 'App 1', 'Floor 2');

SELECT 1 AS [AddressAttribute/@ID]
      ,a.StreetNumber [AddressAttribute/AddressAttributeValue/Value]
      ,''
      ,2 AS [AddressAttribute/@ID]
      ,a.Apartment [AddressAttribute/AddressAttributeValue/Value]
      ,''
      ,3 AS [AddressAttribute/@ID]
      ,a.Floor AS [AddressAttribute/AddressAttributeValue/Value]
      ,''
FROM @Addr AS a      
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Attributes');
```

The result

```
<Attributes>
  <AddressAttribute ID="1">
    <AddressAttributeValue>
      <Value>SomeStreet</Value>
    </AddressAttributeValue>
  </AddressAttribute>
  <AddressAttribute ID="2">
    <AddressAttributeValue>
      <Value>App 1</Value>
    </AddressAttributeValue>
  </AddressAttribute>
  <AddressAttribute ID="3">
    <AddressAttributeValue>
      <Value>Floor 2</Value>
    </AddressAttributeValue>
  </AddressAttribute>
</Attributes>
```